# Download CSV link Python Requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to click 'download csv' button on this site 'https://fplreview.com/team-planner/#forecast_table' using python requests. I've played around with Chrome developer tools to try get the POST requests which got me to this page but when I click the button I can't see anything happening in Network traffic.
I'm performing an initial post and saving the html page down using beautiful soup and it looks like I am on the right page but how to actually save the csv is eluding me. I've attached my current code below. Thanks.
`

```
import requests
import bs4

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://fplreview.com/team-planner/'

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Referer": "https://fplreview.com/team-planner/"
    }

    data = {
        'HiveMind':'Yes',
        'Weeks': 5,
        'TeamID': 123
    }
    
    resp = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'lxml')
    with open('soup.html','w',encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```

`

Comment: I think, you will need a tool such as ```selenium``` for the website interactions<

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with selenium earlier (with help from this site) but was wondering if it was possible to do with requests as I wouldn't need to keep chromedriver updated etc.

Comment: Did you take a closer look to what the response body looks like?